# jQuery isn't firing even though it's loaded in the Rails 4 application (with jquery.turbolinks loaded)

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax, haml

I have a rails app where the jQuery isn't firing on the page when a link is clicked, although it should be. What I want to have happen is if the link is clicked, then the alert messages go off and the AJAX response is sent to the controller. I have turned off the turbolinks for the link clicked, as well as loaded jquery.turbolinks, which should have solved the problem for this link (and has in the past). I am using Ruby on Rails 4. Any insight is welcome!

In my index.html.haml file located in `views`, I have

```
= link_to "To be added", "#", :class => "levelup", 'data-no-turbolink' => true
```

Now in my `application.js` file in my `javascripts` folder, I have these lines loaded:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

The `stats_uploader.js` file, located in the `javascripts` folder, which presumably should do the alerts and ajax file contains this:

```
$('.levelup').click(function() { 
  alert("Yeah");

  var level = $('.playerlevel').text();
  alert(level); //Pat
  level++;
  alert(level); //Pat

  $.ajax({type: "GET",

    url: $(this).attr("href"),
    dataType: "script",
    data:  level ,
    error: function() {
      alert("AJAX failed");
    },
    success: function() {
      alert("Success");
    }

  });
});
```

When I view source on the page, I get these relevant lines signifying that the stats_uploader form has been loaded, as well the appropriate classes being applied to the elements.

```
    <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.turbolinks.js?body=1"></script>
    <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1"></script>
    <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/stats_uploader.js?body=1"></script>

...
...
...
...
      <div class='container'>
        yessir
        Player Level
        <div class='playerlevel'>
          1
        </div>
        <!-- TODO Make Buttons to click on -->
        <a class="levelup" data-no-turbolink="true" href="#">To be added</a>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your page is structured as shown, then the problem is probably that you're trying to wire up the click handler on a link that does not yet exist in the page.  You'll want to wrap your `click` setup in a `$(document).ready` function:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.levelup').click(function() { ... });
});
```

Or a shorter form:

```
$(function() {
  $('.levelup').click(function() { ... });
});
```

Comment: Hey thank you a bunch. This wasn't working yesterday, but it is today so I guess the proof is in the pudding. Thanks!